# git: after I merge from work branch to master, what I will do next?

Tags: git, workflow

I'm confused by the following workflow:

1. I check out to work-branch to edit/add some,
2. then commit to work-branch,
3. switch to master( maybe pull from servers)
4. merge from work-branch
5. and commit to master (maybe push to server)
   and then 2 action:
6. Finally I switch to work-branch and merge master to update the newest code
7. or I delete work-branch and then create new work-branch

Of steps 6 and 7, which one is correct?

Comment: Both or none can be correct. Read on git workflows (just google the term), e.g. this https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's no correct one, it depends on how you want to manage the updates you make. However six looks a bit redundant since work should have already all the code updated with the workflow you exposed. It's up to you, if you want to have as many branches as patches or sprints to keep track of them over time or you want to have a stable branch and a bleeding-edge one, it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose option 7; Create a new local branch for each issue you want to resolve and, when you're done, merge this issue to local master and upload to server. Then, delete your local work-branch ;)